# Understanding analog noise propagation

Tags: analog, audio, noise

### Background

I am designing a low noise gain section for a power amplifier. This section consists of 2 parts:

- the input section, taking care of gain
- a single-ended to balanced buffer with unity gain (doubling with added inverter)

After extensive simulation and tweaking I managed to get to very low simulated noise output figures of -115,1dBu (20-20kHz) for the input/gain section and -117.6dBu for the differential converter/buffer.

### Known facts

- I am aware that noise in opamp configurations can sometimes have a larger than signal gain (but I can't see how this is related to this problem, nevertheless I like to mention it).
- I am aware that noise can be added with the rule: Total noise = SQRT(N1^2 + N2^2)
- I am aware that the above rule is only valid if noise sources are uncorrelated (as in originated from different parts for example).

### Assumptions and question

- As far as I see it, input gain section and balanced buffer stage are uncorrelated.
- The balanced buffer stage doubles voltage. So if I tie this to the output of the buffer stage, i should be able to add noise by adding twice the input/gain stage noise plus the balanced buffer stage.

If I do this, here are the figures:

- gain stage simulated noise output is 1.37µVRMS (-115dBu)
- balanced buffer stage (differential) simulated noise output is 1.02µVRMS (-117.6 dBu)
- adding these as described leads to SQRT((2*1.37µV)^2 + 1.02µV^2) = 2.92 µVRMS (-108.5 dBu)

If I simulate both sections cascaded, however, I get a different noise output (20-20kHz integrated) of 3.16µVRMS or -107.8dBu.  That's  a 0.7dB difference.

Am I making some wrong assumptions, should i check some overlooked details or is this an effect of other effects that I don't understand or know about? I basically want to understand why the cascaded simulated result is different from the calculated result.

### Edit

first stage circuit:
[image]

second stage circuit:
[image]

Comment: What's the output impedance of the 1st stage? What's the input impedance of the 2nd stage?

Comment: If you add 2x the output stage noise (once for each leg) it comes out pretty close. Might that be what's happening?

Comment: output impedance of first stage is an opamp output, so near zero, input impedance of second stage is an opamp unity buffer input, so near infinite.

Comment: "I am aware that noise in opamp configurations can sometimes have a larger than signal gain (but I can't see how this is related to this problem, nevertheless I like to mention it)." Could we see your opamp configurations?

Comment: output noise of second stage is already measured across the differential output. Both when simulating independently and cascaded